# Change position of textbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change the position of these textboxes in the load of my view ?

I want to have these chexboxes under the correct radio button when I load my page.

I already have it when I click on a radio button, but not in the load.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3qN5/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        var home = $(this).closest('div');
        var div = $('#parametersFinancial').detach().appendTo(home);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Y3qN5/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var moveIt = function($element){
        var home = $element.closest('div');
        var div = $('#parametersFinancial').appendTo(home);
    }
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        moveIt($(this));
    });
    moveIt($("input[type=radio]:checked"));
});
```

basically extract the bit that does the work and call it on load as well as on the clicks.

Note: that you don't need `detach` as the DOM elements will be moved by `appendTo`

Answer (score 1):

Just call function when your elements is loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3qN5/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        doStuff($(this));
    });

    doStuff($('checked radio button'));
});
```